# R: Find out which observations are located in each "bar" of the histogram

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, histogram, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I have the following data:

```
     a = rnorm(1000,10,1)
     b = rnorm(200,3,1)
     c = rnorm(200,13,1)
    
    d = c(a,b,c)
index <- 1:1400

my_data = data.frame(index,d)
```

I can make the following histograms of the same data by adjusting the "bin" length (via the "breaks" option):

```
hist(my_data, breaks = 10, main = "Histogram #1, Breaks = 10")
 hist(my_data, breaks = 100, main = "Histogram #2, Breaks = 100")
 hist(my_data, breaks = 5, main = "Histogram #3, Breaks = 5")
```

[image]

**My Question:** In each one of these histograms there are a different number of "bars" (i.e. bins). For example, in the first histogram there are 8 bars and in the third histogram there are 4 bars. For each one of these histograms, is there a way to find out which observations (from the original file "d") are located in each bar?

Right now, I am trying to manually do this, e.g. (for histogram #3)

```
histogram3_bar1 <- my_data[which(my_data$d < 5 & my_data$d > 0), ]
histogram3_bar2 <- my_data[which(my_data$d < 10 & my_data$d > 5), ]
histogram3_bar3 <- my_data[which(my_data$d < 15 & my_data$d > 10), ]
histogram3_bar4 <- my_data[which(my_data$d < 15 & my_data$d > 20), ]


head(histogram3_bar1)

    index        d
1001  1001 4.156393
1002  1002 3.358958
1003  1003 1.605904
1004  1004 3.603535
1006  1006 2.943456
1007  1007 1.586542
```

But is there a more "efficient" way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you want `cut()`, maybe used with `split()`

Comment: @ Moody_Mudskipper: thank you for your reply! I will look into this function - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hist` itself can provide for the solution to the question's problem, to find out which data points are in which intervals. `hist` returns a list with first member `breaks`

First, make the problem reproducible by setting the RNG seed.

```
set.seed(2021)
a = rnorm(1000,10,1)
b = rnorm(200,3,1)
c = rnorm(200,13,1)
d = c(a,b,c)
```

Now, save the return value of `hist` and have `findInterval` tell the bins where each data points are in.

```
h1 <- hist(d, breaks = 10)
f1 <- findInterval(d, h1$breaks)

h1$breaks
# [1] -2  0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16

head(f1)
#[1] 6 7 7 7 7 6
```

The first six observations are intervals 6 and 7 with end points 8, 10 and 12, as can be seen indexing `d` by `f1`:

```
head(d[f1])
#[1]  8.07743 10.26174 10.26174 10.26174 10.26174  8.07743
```

As for whether the intervals given by end points 8, 10 and 12 are left- or right-closed, see `help("findInterval")`.

As a final check, table the values returned by `findInterval` and see if they match the histogram's counts.

```
table(f1)
#f1
#  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
#  2  34 130  34  17 478 512 169  24 
h1$counts
#[1]   2  34 130  34  17 478 512 169  24
```

To have the intervals for each data point, the following

```
bins <- data.frame(bin = f1, min = h1$breaks[f1], max = h1$breaks[f1 + 1L])
head(bins)
#  bin min max
#1   6   8  10
#2   7  10  12
#3   7  10  12
#4   7  10  12
#5   7  10  12
#6   6   8  10
```

Comment: @ Rui Bandaras : thank you for your answer! is there a way to add the "min-max range" for each of these cuts? thank you!

Comment: @stats555 By to add do you mean to define them manually or to get the ones `hist` used? (The answer is be yes to both.)

Comment: Rui Bandaras: thank you for your reply! i was referring to the ones that hist used? thank you!

Comment: @stats555 Try `minmax <- data.frame(min = h1$breaks[f1], max = h1$breaks[f1 + 1L]);head(minmax)`. Will edit the question with this.

Comment: thank you so much for all your help!